# Solving homogeneous exponential system

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose we want to minimize the following energy function
\begin{equation}
\min_{\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}}  \|\boldsymbol{Ax} - e^{\boldsymbol{By}} \|_2^2
\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m, n}, \boldsymbol{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{m, k}$, with $n$ and $k$ less than $m$.

**Questions:**

1. Is the above optimization convex?
2. Is there a closed-form solution for the above problem? I know $\|\boldsymbol{Ax} - \boldsymbol{By}\|$ can be solved up to a scale ambiguity via SVD, I have no idea whether the above minimization can also be solved.

Comment: How do you define $e^{By}$ given that $B$ is a matrix and $y$ (I guess) is a vector?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Yes, $\boldsymbol{B}$ is a matrix and $\boldsymbol{y}$ is a vector. let's say $\boldsymbol{z} = \boldsymbol{By}$ is also a vector, $e(\cdot)$ is an exponential operator, $e^{\boldsymbol{z}}$ is also a vector defined by the element-wise exponential of $\boldsymbol{z}$.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the above optimization convex ?

Yes, it is, as `squared-l2-norm` is a convex function by the definition.

> Is there a closed-form solution for the above problem ?

The problem seems to be not well conditioned, i.e. we could solve it by making $x$ exponentially small positive value, and $y$ exponentially large negative value, will do the job.

e.x. $ \forall x_i = 10^{-6}, \ \forall y_i = -10^{6}$

\begin{equation}
\min_{\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}}  \|\boldsymbol{Ax} - e^{\boldsymbol{By}} \|_2^2 \approx 0
\end{equation}

So there's no need to a closed-form solution.

Moreover $B$ is not a square matrix, which implies there's no analytical solution for this system.